# Exclude files from a submodule using maven is not working

Tags: maven, command-line, parent-pom

I have a multi-module project is the following structure:

```
ROOT
Module A
-- A_pom.xml
Module B depends on Module A
-- src 
--- com.mycompany
---- App 1
---- App 2
-- B_pom.xml
-- B_App1_pom.xml
-- B_App2_pom.xml
pom.xml  <!-- default parent pom fiel -->
second_parent_pom.xml
```

**The pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>company</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Parent</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>module-A</module>
        <module>module-B/</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

From ROOT directory `mvn package` helped me to build both jar files `A.jar` and `B.jar` (this include App 1 and App 2)

Now I am looking a way to build both jar files but that will include only App 1. But I have tried the following code but no result.

```
<build>
    [...]
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                <excludes> 
                <exclude>/../Module_B/src/com/mycompany/App2</exclude>
                </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

When I try to specify the `B_App2_pom.xml` from ROOT directory, it is still pointing to "pom.xml" which make me get the same 2 jar files `A.jar` and `B.jar` instead of `A.jar and B_App2.jar`.
Also, I have tried to create another parent pom file that

**The Second Parent Pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>company</groupId>
    <artifactId>SecondParent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>SecondParent</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>module-A/B_App1_pom.xml</module>
        <module>module-B/B_App2_pom.xml</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `<module>module-A/B_App1_pom.xml</module>` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Yeah, it was my last try. and you're right it didn't pass. I was getting the mentioned error: sub-module pom is pointing to the default parent pom. Thanks. Do you know how to know do it right. I have read that only one parent pom is allowed.

Comment: @Mams Please share B's pom.xml as well.